# Leaflet in R: How to generate multiple icons

Tags: r, leaflet, icons

I have a data frame that contains a list of all sports venues in my state.

Here is a list of the column names in my data frame (pretty self explanatory):

```
[1] "City"       "latitude"   "longitude"  "Rank"       "Population" "County"    
[7] "Desc"
```

I have created all icons below:

```
library(leaflet)
NHL <- makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www-league.nhlstatic.com/images/logos/league-dark/133-flat.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 31, 
    iconAnchorY = 16,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2)
MLB <- makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www.mlbstatic.com/team-logos/league-on-dark/1.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 31, 
    iconAnchorY = 16,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2)
MLS <-makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://league-mp7static.mlsdigital.net/styles/non-retina_desktop_logo/s3/logo25-77x77_0.png?LzMdhn2DU4GXKEjKfJ2QYWMaQKQIk7VQ&itok=ZtYZ58tI",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 31, 
    iconAnchorY = 16,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2)
NBA <-makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://seeklogo.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/NBA-logo.png",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 31, 
    iconAnchorY = 16,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2)
NFL <-makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://static.nfl.com/static/content/public/static/wildcat/assets/img/application-shell/shield/default.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 31, 
    iconAnchorY = 16,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2)
```

I am trying to create a leaflet plot that highlights each sports team venue in my state by showing the relevant icon. The code below will only show a single icon (whichever is first in the icon = list)

```
df %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(lat = df$Latitude, lng = df$Longitude, icon = c(MLB, NHL, NFL, MLS, NBA))
```

I've also created another data frame (df2; below) that contains each venue (Stadium Name) and the relevant league (NFL/NHL/etc) and I've tried to pass this to "icon = df2$League" but it does not recognize it as an object. Any ideas?

```
> colnames(df2)
[1] "Club"      "Sport"     "League"    "Symbol"    "Venue"     "City"      "Latitude" 
[8] "Longitude"
```

Comment: Looks like your dataframe (df) has colnames of latitude/longitude, but your leaflet call tries to use Latitude and Longitude. If this isn't the case, could you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide reproducible data so I've made up some example data assuming your df has a column with the league name, which we can use to match the name of the icon:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

# generate example data
set.seed(2020)
venues <- c('NHL', 'MLB', 'MLS', 'NBA', 'NFL')
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

df <- st_sample(nc, 5) %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as.data.frame 
df$league <- venues

df

#>           X        Y league
#> 1 -78.58785 35.94350    NHL
#> 2 -80.82830 35.88732    MLB
#> 3 -78.83967 36.11236    MLS
#> 4 -80.09532 35.01562    NBA
#> 5 -83.72636 35.33204    NFL
```

All we need to do is create a named `iconList` where the name of the icon matches the name in the "league" column of our dataframe. With `~iconSet[league]` we can ensure the correct icon is being used for each point in the df.

```
# create iconSet
iconSet <- iconList(NHL= NHL,
                    MLB =MLB, 
                    MLS = MLS,
                    NBA = NBA,
                    NFL = NFL)

# map
leaflet(df) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=~X, lat=~Y, icon = ~iconSet[league])
```

[image: Leaflet iconList example]

Comment: Works great! Just out of curiosity, why do you use a ~ before X, Y and iconSet? I've never seen that before. Is it a personal preference?

Comment: Yep its personal preference. The 'formula notation' `~` allows us to reference elements from the `data` environment without the need for `data$X` or `data$Y` which is a bit neater. It also saves a lot of typing if making something like a popup where we're referencing multiple columns of data. [More from the docs](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/map_widget.html)